# Testing web site with blackberry curve

Tags: asp.net, blackberry

I'm developing an asp.net web site to work on mobile devices.  Is going ok and works fine with android and iphone.  I've no got around to testing it with blackberry in my balcberry curve.  When i first tried everything looked good b ut then i noticed that some od the autopost back on dropdowns etc did not work.  Some research time later i turn out out that by default that blackberries do not support this and that I need a Blackberr.browser file to allow that type of functionality to work.   I following this link...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/BlackberryASPNET.aspx

After doing this my blakberry will not load the site at all, i just get connection timeouts.  So i tried removing the blackberry.browser file, read loading the assembley in an attempt to get back to where is was, but still the site will not connect.  I've refreshed iis, recycled app pools and even rebooted.  I have a QA site on another box that the blackberry will connect to, but my development machine it does not like anymore:-(.

Any one got any ideas in what is going on?

Thanks for any help.

Richard

Answer (score -1):

I have also suffered with the pain of developing (actually optimizing) websites for BlackBerry and Symbian, and I understand your suffering.

As you're using BlackBerry Curve, I suppose you're using a MDS server simulator on your development machine to let the BlackBerry Emulator connect to Internet.

Although I am not sure if you're even using a simulator.

I also have come across some simulators which just won't connect to the Internet no matter how hard you try with MDS server and all.

I hope you're not stuck with any issue related to the above said things mate.

Are you trying to connect your localhost with your BB?

Comment: I'm using an actual device, although i did try the simulator and came accross the pain of getting that to work too, still not managed that one yet.  The device is connected up to our wireless network and can run out QA version.

Comment: This is extremely weird. Are you using JDE or Eclipse to get a log out? Although I am not sure if it will help